# Purpose of the csx folder in Azure projects?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, directory-structure

I'm fairly new to Azure but I noticed that Visual Studio auto-creates the following folders (among others)

```
...
/<nameOfAzureProject>/bin
/<nameOfAzureProject>/obj
/<nameOfAzureProject>/csx <==
...
```

Now the bin and obj folders are fairly standard. But I'm not clear about the purpose of the **csx** folder. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use and behavior of a specific software development tool. Such questions are better suited to Stack Overflow, however this question is too old to migrate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It contains a packaged version of your project. I found a [blog entry](http://andrewmatthewthompson.blogspot.com/2011/12/deploying-packages-to-azure-compute.html) mentioning it.

> Before an Azure package can be deployed to the emulator it must first be packaged. Since v1.4 of the Windows Azure Tools, the `csx` folder and its contents are no longer generated during compilation... So in order to force the generation of the `csx` folder we need to specify that the package should be generated for the compute emulator within the Azure project file...
>
> **:: Deploying to the Azure Compute Emulator**
>
> Now that we have the `csx` package folder generated after each compilation run we can use the CSRun command-line tool to deploy the folder to the emulator...